# Cannot retrieve Contact schemas using Fuel REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I need to retrieve the collection of all Contact data schemas contained in an account. I'm using this [documented method](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/schemasCollection.html):

```
Authorization: Bearer [accessToken]
Content-Type: application/json
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/schemas
```

But this returns an error:

```
{
    "documentation": "https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/404",
    "errorcode": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
}
```

I've tried other GET requests for Contact methods and they don't work either.
Please can someone clarify what the correct route should be? I'm thinking this route pattern should work as I'm using the following URL for the `contactEvents` method and this works fine:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/contactEvents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct route is:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/schema
```

'schema' without the trailing 's'.  We'll correct the documentation.